# enabling search option in combobox

Tags: c#, asp.net, combobox

```
<asp:ComboBox ID="ddlfrom"  runat="server"  
  DataTextField="name" DataValueField="name" MaxLength="0" 
    style="display: inline;" 


 AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend">

  </asp:ComboBox>
```

> this is the asp code for my combobox...i am populating my combobox from database.I have all the city names in my combobox.Now i have enabled suggest append as you can see..but its not searching the elemnts anywhere from the names..mean when i type "SBC" code it searches for bangalore city..but i need that when i type "bang" in this also it should show me bangalore city..the same functionality as we have in makemytrip site..how can i do that..??..plzz help..

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for autocomplete feature.
See this [link](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox).

You can do it using the jQuery.ajax functions. This [Article](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/03/jquery-ui-autocomplete-textbox-with.html) explains how you can do it.

Comment: well where to add that code that is given in aspx part ?...i am using .net 4.0 version.

Comment: Download the sample code from the site and try doing it yourself. Its simple to do.

Comment: do i have to add web service also..?

Comment: no, you can use `[WebMethod]` decorated public static methods instead of webservice. In the example such page methods are used.